# OLS reinterpretation (?)

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, residuals

I have read on a book written by a professor something similar to the following and want to check this statement on the forum, since it is the first time I have heard it. I have read that the OLS problem may be re-expressed as the minimization of the matrix of residuals $ee^{T}$ (assume $e=y-\beta x$ is a column vector, therefore $ee^{T}$ is a matrix), where minimizing such matrix means that, given **any** psd matrix of appropriate size $A$, then the matrix $B=A-ee^{T}$ is positive semidefinite.

Take for clarity the special case in which $y$ is a linear combination of $x$ with weights $\beta$, so the true error term is trivial: by applying OLS and estimating the sensitivities, we can retrieve $\beta$ ending up with 0 residuals (where here 0 denotes a vector of 0s of an appropriate size). Therefore, in this particular case, the matrix $ee^{T}$ is a matrix made of 0s and such analogy would make sense. But does it make any sense to generalize this concept?

I just want to check with you the correctness of this statement (which of course is not mine!). In case you have some references pointing to this, please share them. Many thanks

Comment: Something must have been lost in translation, because this makes no sense.  Unless $ee^\prime$ is the zero matrix, you may take $A=ee^\prime/2$ which is psd and find that $B=-ee^\prime/2$ is not psd.  Please double-check your reference and, if possible, quote it precisely.

Comment: @whuber I am a little bit troubled now to research the source and post it and believe me if I tell you that, if I did, you would see how “quick and opaque” the comment is, which is why I indeed posted the question.. it was not a clear and exhaustive speech with proofs, otherwise I would likely have had nothing to ask.. and, when I think about the context, it may hinted at a case where the residuals where 0 (even if the comment was put down in a general sense).. so I agree with your comment, and that’s why I was willing to check it on the forum. However, if I retrieve the source, I will post it